# Docker does not resolve company network: UnknownHostException

Tags: docker

I am inside VPN (for my company) and when I try to reach internal network for installations, it just works fine.

But now when I am inside my container and do the installation, I get the following error

```
Stack trace:java.net.UnknownHostException: internal.qa.sjc.com: unknown error
```

How can I resolve to this address from inside my container?

Comment: Does the container can ping company LAN? Perform `nslookup` queries? How does the container network stack is (i.e., what is the network mode)?

Comment: This is default container, meaning it uses bridge network stack

Comment: What about the other questions? :)

Comment: I added the `DNS` entries in my container's `/etc/resolv.conf` and that was it

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers by default use public Google DNS servers for name resolution.   So unless your hosts publicly resolve via google DNS -- you need to supply your own.

[Docker DNS docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/)